# jQuery Multiple Toggles Misbehaving?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have 3 buttons, on hover they show and image and on click they load a div however, when i click between them the div sometimes fails to load and it seems to get all muddled turning each other on and off.

I’ve done a rough [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8CFde/4/) to explain...

```
//Button One
    $("li.chem-flow a").hover(function () {

              $("img.chem-flow-detail").fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );

             })

    $("li.chem-flow a").click(function () {

              $(".system-full-top").fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );

             })      


    //Button Two         
    $("li.power-boost a").hover(function () {

              $("img.power-boost-detail").fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );

            })

     $("li.power-boost a").click(function () {

              $(".system-full-top").fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );

             })         


     //Button Three         
     $("li.power-box a").hover(function () {

              $("img.power-box-detail").fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );

            }) 

     $("li.power-box a").click(function () {

              $(".system-full-top").fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );

             })
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your all `.fadeToggle()` with prepending `.stop(true, true)`:

```
.stop(true, true).fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
```

so for example:

```
$("li.chem-flow a").hover(function () {
   $("img.chem-flow-detail").stop(true, true).fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```

#### [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8CFde/5/)

Comment: That still seems to be doing what mine was, click another one and it fades out when it should be fading in? Hover is fine...